# How to rewrite URL paths to query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# To remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# To remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ (.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To check whether the PHP file exists and set it back internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

# To redirect /index to root
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Assume there is a file.php in the root directory and v1,v2,... are my query string inputs and the URL below is requested:

```
http://domain.tld/file/v1/v2...
```

I simply need to send v1,v2,... as HTTP GET to the file.php using .htaccess and it should work with any other PHP file names and in case of possibility any number of inputs, otherwise handling up to 3 inputs is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `file.php` is just a template name, and is not limited to that particular name. You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1.php?params=$2 [NC,L]
```

Now, in the `file.php`, you will get the passed query arguments as:

```
$_GET['params']  // which will be of the form v1/v2/v3...
```

Comment: Thanks, Should I only add this at the first of my .htaccess without any other change to the previous codes?

Comment: @4L3X Put it just after you remove `.php`.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work and caused an internal server error.

Comment: Which url are you visiting?

Comment: @4L3X Updated the post above. Try now